# How can I use my Intel HD GPU at the same time as my NVIDIA GPU on a Desktop system?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

So, I've found only a handful of questions / articles about this topic but in pretty much all cases it's about laptops. This is very different because it's usually related to Nvidia Optimus sort of things.

### Goal

What I am trying to achieve is to connect as many displays as possible to my Desktop PC. I've got a NVIDIA 780TI with 2x DVI, 1x HDMI and 1 Display port. My motherboard has 1 HDMI, 1 DVI and 1 VGA port.

### Current state

I've already been working with **3x 27 inch monitors using 2x DVI and 1x HDMI on the NVIDIA GPU**. But I've found a couple of old screens which I would like to connect as monitoring devices to the motherboard. The problem is **Ubuntu doesn't really recognize the 4th screen that is connected through VGA to the motherboard**.

I do know it is possible from a hardware point of view as this does actually work out of the box on my Windows installation.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is a picture of what it looks like now after booting.
It seems like at first it does actually detect the fourth display, but then it just stops "talking" to it and it's buffer is just stuck with the Ubuntu loading screen.

*(the top screen is connected through the motherboard VGA connector. the others using the nvidia gfx card)*
[image: Top screen]

Comment: I always thought this was impossible. I never got any success on Dell desktops. Usually you get an error at boot, and you can't ignore it.

Comment: I'm actually quite perplexed that no one else has been trying this up until now, especially since it is possible on Windows; Ubuntu should be able to pull this of too

Comment: Maybe because a lot of us get the bios error when trying to do that. Which motherboard do you have?

Comment: I don't think the BIOS/Motherboard has a lot to do with this (apart from the fact you can turn off Intel HD Graphics from within the BIOS). Especially since this 4 screen setup works perfectly in Windows. (if it had something todo with a BIOS error windows wouldn't work either right?)

And that's my point, this works without any setup / out of the box on Windows. So there is no actual hardware limitations in play here, this seems to be a software (os/driver/kernel) issue

Comment: On a dell, the bios/motherboard will reject this sort of configuration. This is what you'd get: http://www.win-pc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Action-is-Required.jpg